# How can I use Ceph to save Terraform state?

Tags: terraform, ceph

I have access to a Ceph instance on my intranet and I see there is an S3 Backend for Terraform state storage. Can I use Ceph as a storage backend?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the `skip_credentials_validation` and `force_path_style` arguments to `true`, as well as specifying the `endpoint` of course.

Here is a copy-and-paste friendly version:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket      = "your-bucket-name"
    key         = "a-key"
    region      = "us-east-1"
    endpoint    = "hostname.for.the.ceph.instance"
    access_key  = "your-access-key"
    secret_key  = "your-secret-key"

    skip_credentials_validation = true
    force_path_style            = true
  }
}
```